# Does --no-ancient-blocks affect on trace_call for the pending block?

Tags: parity, openethereum

Please explain how --no-ancient-blocks flag works for openethereum.

I've checked that with this flag I won't be able to make requests eth_getBlockByNumber for ancient blocks.

But what about transactions for pending blocks that rely on the state of contracts which were created in the ancient blocks?

For example,  there is a contract 0x123123123123123123 which was created in block_number=1. This contract has a public method getMyValue() which returns a stored value my_value. This state my_value was set in block_number=1.

Is it possible to make trace_call for the pending block to this contract and get this my_value for openethereum node which was synced with --no-ancient-flag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the Solidity docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.5.3/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties

Transactions can only access at most state that is 256 blocks old. That is, the 256th previous block hash. If you're trying to trace a transaction based on a block far enough in the past such that the transaction ends up referencing an ancient block, it's likely (though I haven't proven experimentally) your call will fail as the state won't exist on your node.

In short: barring any larger limitations of the client, tracing on the pending block without ancient blocks should be fine.